# Why is not there a 'OneTimeToSource' option in binding modes?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

One of the first things you learn when you working with WPF is the `BindingMode` enum:

- `OneWay`: Updates the binding target (target) property when the binding source (source) changes.
- `OneWayToSource`: Updates the source property when the target property changes.
- `TwoWay`: Causes changes to either the source property or the target property to automatically update the other.
- `OneTime`: Updates the binding target when the application starts or when the data context changes.

I wonder why there is no `OneTimeToSource` mode. Something like:

- `OneTimeToSource`: Updates the binding source when the target changes.

I thought that this mode is not available for some particular reason (such as not breaking a specific pattern) but at the same time I also find this mode extremely useful, like establish the properties of the source from target (like config, for example) at the moment of coupling.

At least, I see it as a way to keep weakly coupled two structures and allow source to adapt to the target according to the properties of the target.

**So, why is not there a 'OneTimeToSource' option in binding modes?**

Comment: You should ask the WPF designers. IMO, it just isn't necessary or in any way useful. At least, it seems that nobody ever missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why there is no OneTimeToSource mode. Something like:
>   OneTimeToSource: Updates the binding source when the target changes.

The existig OneWayToSource works exactly like this, i.e. it updates the source property *each time* the target property is set to a new value.

Using a One**Time**ToSource mode wouldn't make much sense as this would just set the source property to the default value of the target property *once* when the view was loaded for the first time.

Then it wouldn't be much of a point setting up the binding in the first place. This mode would for example set the string source property of a view model that was bound to a TextBox in the view to an empty string or a null reference which already is the default value for a string.